# How to I supply variable to write() in python

Tags: python

```
import sys
import paramiko as pm
import os


def mdbAuto(req):
        HOST = 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'
        USER = 'user'
        PASSWORD = 'password'

        client = pm.SSHClient()
        client.load_system_host_keys()
        client.set_missing_host_key_policy(pm.AutoAddPolicy())
        client.connect(HOST, username=USER, password=PASSWORD)

        channel = client.invoke_shell()
        stdin = channel.makefile('wb')
        stdout = channel.makefile('rb')
        reqID = int(req)
        print reqID
        stdin.write('''
        cd /root/MDB2GRANITE/
        python pravinGranite.py %d
        ls
        exit
        ''')%reqID
        print stdout.read()

        stdout.close()
        stdin.close()
        client.close()


if __name__== "__main__":
        req = sys.argv[1]
        mdbAuto(req)
```

The above code gives me error as unsupported operand type.
How do supply variable value to stdin.write function. I guess that stdin.write function write the line as it is to command-line. Is there a way I can manipulate %d to make it accept value of reqID? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @DonQuestion The code references variables named `stdin` and `stdout` which have the opposite of the regular meaning.  This is not `sys.stdin` at all.  One certainly has to wonder why the OP chose to name his variables so utterly confusingly, but `stdin` really does refer to a writable channel.

Comment: @triplee: You are right, thanks! Seems like i fluked that one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct syntax is

```
handle.write('format string %d' % value)
```

not

```
handle.write('format string %d') % value
```

Going forward, perhaps you should consider switching to the [Python3 string formatting facility](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) instead, which is also avaiable in >= 2.6;

```
handle.write('format string {0!d}'.format(value))
```